# Heroku slow reconnect

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

My application (Rails 3.2.12) uses 1 web dyno and 0 worker dyno, deployed using default configuration on Heroku. Not so many gems are used, and no background works running.

Normally - and most of the time - the app loads very fast. 
But sometimes, somehow the connection becomes very very slow, and end up at time out.
And the mystery is that - during that time - loading my website from a second computer (which is also on the same network) is very fast.
Loading another websites from the first computer is also very fast.

And based on experiment, the connection would easily be fixed, when I:
(1) stop all browser tabs which are still in progress of loading my website
(2) wait for a few seconds (3-5 seconds)
(3) open new tab and open my website again

I believe it's not my browser problem since it only happen for my web app.
And it's also not due to dyno-idling as well since the website is in production and never idle for more than 3 minutes (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#dyno-idling)

Comment: what exactly is your question? the problem is because of dyno-idling. Richard Brown has a good solution

Comment: I have NewRelics regularly ping-ing the website. Moreover, the web got some traffics per minute.

Comment: I suspect that Heroku/Rails maintains a list of IPs which have sent request command. If at that time the server is busy processing another request, the request is put into the queue.

What is weird is that:
Another request coming from different computer could be processed instantly but the request coming before is not replied.

Answer (score 2):

You can either increase your dynos to 2 or more (no more idling) or do what I do: Use [Pingdom](http://www.pingdom.com) to ping my site at an interval.  This keeps the site from idling (and also lets me know if the site goes down...)

Comment: I don't think it's because of dyno idling.
The website is up and got many requests per minute.
Moreover, I also use NewRelic to ping regularly.